# unscoped enums in C code with VS2015

Tags: c, c++11, visual-c++, enums, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to compile the psutil module for Python, using VS 2015 and the Windows 10 SDK.  Compilation fails with the following error:

```
c:\users\builder\documents\code\psutil\psutil\arch\windows\ntextapi.h(212): error C2365: 'ProcessBreakOnTermination': redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um\winternl.h(308): note: see declaration of 'ProcessBreakOnTermination'
c:\users\builder\documents\code\psutil\psutil\arch\windows\ntextapi.h(212): error C2086: '_PROCESSINFOCLASS2 ProcessBreakOnTermination': redefinition
c:\users\builder\documents\code\psutil\psutil\arch\windows\ntextapi.h(212): note: see declaration of 'ProcessBreakOnTermination'
```

Further investigation shows ProcessBreakOnTermination is part of an enum (PROCESSINFOCLASS) in winternl.h.

I believe this has to do with C++11's enforcement of scoped enums: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2dzy4k6e(v=vs.110).aspx

However, I am lost on how to address this issue.  If I try to add the class or struct bits as detailed on that MS website, I get compiler errors, since this is being compiled as C code.  Why should the C++11 rules apply to C code here?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was to wrap the offending dual-defined symbols in a #if.

```
(start of enum)
(last good entry)
#if _MSC_VER < 1900
(offending enum entry)
#endif
(next entry) = (last_good_entry)+2
```

Any nicer solutions are welcome!